# Adding markers in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, markers

I'm a beginner with JS.

I'm trying to add a map to my website using Leaflet. I followed the [Quick Start Guide](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/), but it looks like adding a marker won't work.

Here is my code :

```js
    <!-- JS Leaflet Map -->
    <script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script> 
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([40.174295, 44.522890], 11);

    var mymap = L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18, attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var marker = L.marker([40.174295, 44.522890]).addTo(mymap);
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Laura

Comment: define won't work... that code is copy paste from their getting started guide, so is hard to tell, can you try using the dev tools and inspect the map, maybe the marker is added but you forgot to add the assets (img/css) that actually shows the pin.

Comment: There is no marker on the map. I get this error : [Img](https://ibb.co/iGsrMk)

Comment: keep only one `var mymap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is here

```
var mymap = L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 18, attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Do not assign the result to mymap variable

Because of that, the next line is receiving a `Layer` instead of a `Map` object

```
var marker = L.marker([40.174295, 44.522890]).addTo(mymap);
```

So, final code should be like this

```
<!-- JS Leaflet Map -->
<script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
<script> 
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([40.174295, 44.522890], 11);

L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 18, attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
}).addTo(mymap);

var marker = L.marker([40.174295, 44.522890]).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Please accept answer and optionally upvote as a way to thank. Also, you're welcome.